# How to connect dense layer when learning relation between field description and categories

Tags: classification, deep-learning, lstm, tensorflow

I have a relation between products that looks like this

[image]

I would like to have a RNN (LSTM) to learn the descriptions of the items in the left column and with a dense layer learn to match a category to a given description. The is also a longer text description to each item (not in the image above) that I would like to pass to the LSTM to eventually improve the "knowledge" about a given item.

I have been trying seq2seq methods and generating new "alike" content, but I don't know how to connect at dense layer to do this classification. Basically both "what input to feed" and "how to chain these" are my questions.

If someone could clarify this for me it would be great.

Comment: I think you are doing a binary classifier which can classify 'indoor' and 'outdoor', so you can merge the 344B and 413 data into a single dataset.  to do this classification you need to add a `Dense(1)` layer after the LSTM layer.

Comment: @Craig.Li sorry if I was not clear. Actually there will be more than 2 categories, my example was too simple. So I cannot use a Boolean approach fot the result/predictions.